# How does this circuit work? BAV99 (3.3V for an ADC)

Tags: voltage, adc, how-does-it-work

I'm having serious difficulties understanding how this circuit works. It's supposed to be around 10V at my test point with the voltage divider, but when I measure it, I get around 3.3V.

It's not clear to me how a diode can consistently reduce my voltage from 10.5V to 3.3V, even when I increase my VBATT voltage.

If someone could explain it to me in the simplest way possible, or in the most engineering terms, I would be happy. Thank you very much.

[image: Simulation circuit]
[image: Real Circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D2 is clamping the voltage at around 3.3V by dumping current into the 3.3V source. This is a common configuration for input protection on integrated circuits where the diodes can provide limited over- and under-voltage protection.

Comment: But how does it limit/dumping the voltage in that way? That's what I can't seem to grasp. I understand the concept, but I can't figure out how that happens. Still, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: The voltage at the test point cannot rise above one diode forward voltage drop above 3.3V since D2 will begin conducting and appear as a short to 3.3V. Recall that an ideal voltage source maintains the same voltage across its terminals *regardless of how much current flows into or out of it*.

Comment: basically because diodes conduct if the voltage direction is favorable. and that conduction messes with the voltage divider.